# I am trying to display Dialog in fragments it show some error in context,same approach works fine in Activity class

Tags: android, android-dialog

> Here is my **CustomProgressDialog** Class in which i am using
>   AysncTask to display dialog, this code work's fine in Activity class
>   but in Fragment it show error in mDailog = new Dialog(context)

**CustomProgressDialog Class**

```
public class CustomProgressDialog extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private Context context;

    public CustomProgressDialog(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    private Dialog mDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mDialog = new Dialog(context);
        mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_bar);
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (mDialog != null) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
            mDialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:188)
        at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:162)
        at com.edu.omsaiinstitute.CustomProgressDialog.onPreExecute(CustomProgressDialog.java:22)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:708)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:655)
        at com.edu.omsaiinstitute.NotesFragment.dataFromFirebase(NotesFragment.java:78)
        at com.edu.omsaiinstitute.NotesFragment.onCreateView(NotesFragment.java:73)
```

Comment: dialogs are already asynchronous why are you doing it in background thread

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you are showing dialog in async task , but the context you want to pass while from fragment is its root activity context so instead of context use getactivity(), this should fix the issue

```
    private Dialog mDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_bar);
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (mDialog != null) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
            mDialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```